# Is the set of the empty set and omega a collection?

Tags: measure-theory

I've recently started to study measure theory and in this respect am reading up on sigma algebras. In this context I saw that sometimes collections are denoted as calligraphic letters (also called algebras) containing other sets. However, for $\mathcal{A} = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ a text I read has "The set $\mathcal{A} = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ for any set $\Omega$". This confused me aboout whether the term 'collection' has any specific restrictions to be used, i. e. whether the sets contained in a collection have to configured in a certain way; my question therefore:

Is the set $\mathcal{A} = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ a collection?

Comment: Some authors in some contexts like to call "collections" things endowed with slightly more structure than a bare set (for instance, a function $A_\bullet:I\to \text{somewhere}$ sending $i\mapsto A_i$). However, without further context, yes, a set could be called a "collection".

Comment: Anyone voting minus 1 feel free to explain.

Comment: @Gae. S. Thanks for the quick answer - I will update the question with context.

Comment: Does your text define the word *collection* to mean the same thing as an algebra of sets?

Comment: I haven't found a definition of collection in the text, unfortunately. It started appearing midtext and I couldn't find a good definition on the web, so far.

Comment: Could it be argued that because $\#\emptyset = 0$ that $\mathcal{A}$ is not a collection, because it only contains a single set ($\Omega$)?

Comment: I asked because you said "also called algebras" which made it sound like the text was defining "collection" in some specific way. But if that is not the case, then they are probably using the word "collection" to mean the same thing as "set". When working with sets whose elements are also sets, sometimes people say "collection of sets" rather than "set of sets" (usually just for aesthetic reasons). But they mean the same thing. So, yes, $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ is perfectly fine collection (or set) of sets.

Comment: Also, fyi, if $\Omega$ is nonempty then $\#\{\emptyset,\Omega\}=2$, regardless of the fact that $\#\emptyset=0$. The singleton $\{\Omega\}$ is still a well-defined collection (but it's not the same as $\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ unless $\Omega=\emptyset$).

Comment: "Collection" and "family" are synonyms for "set".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection is a set in this context.

The set $\mathcal A$ is a set of set, so $\mathcal A$ is definitely a set.
Because it is a set of sets, it is sometimes informally called
a *collection* or a *collection of sets*

(sometimes collection refers to something slightly different, see the comment of Gae. S., but not in this context.)